# Saving filled contour plots to PDF in R gives pixelated results

Tags: r, pdf, plot, contour, vector-graphics

Saving the output of one of `R`'s built-in examples for the `filled.contour` function to PDF:

```
pdf('test.pdf')
require("grDevices")
filled.contour(volcano, asp = 1)
dev.off()
```

produces a discretised result (see below). Is there any way to fix this? System info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
```

[image]

Edit after the accepted answer:

The problem is actually reported in the documentation of the `pdf` function:

```
If you see problems with PDF output, do remember that the
problem is much more likely to be in your viewer than in R ... 
Symptoms for which the viewer has been at fault are apparent 
grids on image plots ...
    
Unfortunately the default viewers on most Linux and macOS 
systems have these problems, and no obvious way to turn off 
graphics anti-aliasing.
```

It's an odd place to document the problem because the subdivision into rectangular segments is clearly caused by `filled.contour` and not by `pdf`. Otherwise `ggplot2`'s output would also suffer from the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is likely a result of antialiasing:  when you display the image, it draws squares one at a time.  As they are being drawn, the edge is a mix of the square colours and the white background, so it is drawn lighter.

Unfortunately, this isn't something that's really under your control.  It's the PDF previewer that is introducing the artifacts.  See this page https://codedocean.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/anti-aliasing-and-image-plots/ for a discussion.

The recommendation there worked for me:  use the `png()` device with `type = "cairo"`.  This gives bitmapped output rather than the vector output of a `pdf()`.

```
png('test.png',type="cairo")
filled.contour(volcano, asp = 1)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Edited to add:

I don't think you can do better with `filled.contour`, but if you are willing to switch to `ggplot2` graphics you can.  When it draws filled contours it appears to do it using polygons, not the `image` style plot that `filled.contour` uses.  This still shows the same antialiasing bugs in the previewer, but now the lines appear along the borders between colours, which is much less irritating.  For example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = as.numeric(row(volcano)-1)/(nrow(volcano)-1),
                 y = as.numeric(col(volcano)-1)/(ncol(volcano)-1),
                 z = as.numeric(volcano))    
pdf('test.pdf')
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z)) + 
  geom_contour_filled()
dev.off()
```

[image: screenshot]

I don't know how to get the same palette as `filled.contour` uses, i.e. `function(n) hcl.colors(n, "YlOrRd", rev = TRUE)`.  Maybe someone else can show us in a comment.

Comment: Yes the vector image is made up of lots of little squares. This seems quite an inefficient way to save the filled contour plot. So there is no way to use the contours as polygons and fill them with a solid colour?

Comment: I believe the `ggplot2::geom_contour_filled` function draws them that way, so it produces better results.  I'll see if I can modify my answer to show what you'd need to do.

Comment: This answers my question. It's a shame that base R can't do this though.

Comment: Given that the PNG output is fine, shouldn't you be asking for a fix in the PDF previewer?  That's where the bug is.

Comment: It's not the previewer. When I open the `filled.contour` PDF in Inkscape, it comes out as a bunch of rectangles. `ggplot::geom_contour_filled`'s output looks fine in the previewer, because it doesn't consist of rectangles.

Comment: You are wrong in two ways:  the `ggplot2` output shows the same effect in a different place:  you can see light edges to the polygon regions.  Those aren't as irritating as the light edges on the rectangles, but they are still a bug.  If Inkscape shows a problem when you plot a dark rectangle beside a dark rectangle, it has the same bug as the previewer that I use.  They should be doing antialiasing, but not the way they are doing it.

Comment: I think that we're talking about different problems here. The first problem is aliasing. As mentioned in the documentation of the pdf function, all pdf viewing software under Linux and MacOS suffers from this issue. The second problem is the needless subdivision of filled contour plots into small rectangles. This problem only occurs in base R and not in `ggplot2`. But of course you are correct that `ggplot2` isn't immune to aliasing elsewhere.